# ListView.view is always null in ListView's delegate

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt-quick

### The setup

I have a `ListView` with some general model and `myDelegate` component.

```
ListView {
    id: myListView
    delegate: myDelegate
    ...
}
```

In `myDelegate` component, I want to set `ListView`'s `currentItem`. I currently do it like this:

```
Component {
    id: myDelegate
    ...
    MouseArea {
        onClicked: myListView.currentIndex = model.index
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected.

### The issue

As commonly known, it's bad practice to use `ListView`'s `id` inside a delegate, since there could be multiple ListView using the same delegate component. So, [ListView.view](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#view-attached-prop) attached property should be used instead.

But if I change the delegate's code like this:

```
Component {
    id: myDelegate
    ...
    MouseArea {
        onClicked: ListView.view.currentIndex = model.index
    }
}
```

I get a `TypeError: Value is null and could not be converted to an object`.

With the following console.logs, I discovered that **`ListView.view` is always null**. I don't understand why. Setting `currentIndex` on `ListView` itself fails too.

```
onClicked: {
    console.log("ListView:", ListView)
    console.log("ListView.view:", ListView.view)
    console.log("ListView.currentIndex:", ListView.currentIndex)
}
...
qml: ListView: QQuickListViewAttached(0x6db0b30)
qml: ListView.view: null
qml: ListView.currentIndex: undefined
```

### Minimal reproducible example

Qt v6.2.1
Empty Qt Quick project in Qt Creator
main.qml:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    width: 150
    height: 350
    visible: true

    Component {
        id: myDelegate

        Rectangle {
            color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "pink" : "lightblue"
            implicitWidth: 150
            implicitHeight: 50

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    ListView.view.currentIndex = model.index
                    console.log("ListView", ListView)
                    console.log("ListView.view", ListView.view)
                }
            }

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: model.index
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: myListView
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 2
        model: 6
        delegate: myDelegate
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc updated

Comment: The MRE must be in your post so I have taken the liberty of copying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attached properties are set in the root of the delegate so if you want to access from a child item then you must use the root as reference:

```
    Component {
        id: myDelegate

        Rectangle {
            id: root_delegate // <---

            color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "pink" : "lightblue"
            implicitWidth: 150
            implicitHeight: 50

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    root_delegate.ListView.view.currentIndex = model.index;
                    console.log("ListView", root_delegate.ListView);
                    console.log("ListView.view", root_delegate.ListView.view);
                }
            }

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: model.index
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: This behavior is weird, since declared properties can be accessed from children directly...

Comment: @DmitrySemenov Better explicit than implicit, use ids to refer to properties or methods of other objects, in addition to being easier to read the code, avoid having this type of bugs